# when i add a child the listener called multiple time and i don't know why .. there is my code

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am working with MVC and I am using firebase realtime database in my app. I am using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` listner to add data in firebase.

#### The problem I'm facing

The listener is called multiple time and the phone stopped working

```kotlin
    override fun insertRapport(rapports: Rapports,userItem: UserItem,uid: String,responseCallback: ResponseCallback) {

        userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                            var rapport = HashMap<String, Rapports>()
                            rapports.id = userRef.push().key.toString()
                            rapport[rapports.id.toString()] = rapports
                            userItem.rapport = rapport
                            userRef.child(uid)
                                .child("rapports").child(rapports.id!!)
                                .setValue(rapports)
                            responseCallback.success()

                userRef.removeEventListener(this)
                        }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

            }

        })
    }
```

Comment: can you show up the log when it stop working

Answer (score 0):

Based on your current code, this wouldn't be the source of your infinite loop.

However, you don't need the value event listener anyway for what you are trying to do.

```
override fun insertRapport(rapports: Rapports, uid: String, responseCallback: ResponseCallback) {
    var newRapportsRef = userRef
        .child(uid)
        .child("rapports")
        .push()

    rapports.id = newRapportsRef.key

    newRapportsRef.setValue(rapports)
        .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                responseCallback.success()
            } else {
                responseCallback.failed()
            }
        })
}
```

Because the Firebase library already returns a [`Task` object](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task), you don't need to use `ResponseCallback`. There is also a [`Tasks` utility class](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks) for common operations you'd do on tasks.

```
override fun insertRapport(rapports: Rapports, uid: String) {
    var newRapportsRef = userRef
        .child(uid)
        .child("rapports")
        .push()

    rapports.id = newRapportsRef.key

    return newRapportsRef.setValue(rapports)
}
```

Or you could use Kotlin's `DatabaseReference.CompletionListener` variant:

```
override fun insertRapport(rapports: Rapports, uid: String, listener: DatabaseReference.CompletionListener?) {
    var newRapportsRef = userRef
        .child(uid)
        .child("rapports")
        .push()

    rapports.id = newRapportsRef.key

    newRapportsRef.setValue(rapports, listener)
}
```

If `userItem.rapport` needs to be updated too, you should do that in it's own listener elsewhere.

```
userItem = /* ... */

// could use a ChildEventListener
ValueEventListener rapportListener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, Rapports>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, Rapports>>() {};
        userItem.rapport = snapshot.getValue(t)
    }

    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        // TODO: Handle errors
    }
}

// attach the listener (in onCreate, etc.)
userRef
  .child(uid)
  .child("rapports")
  .addValueEventListener(rapportListener)

// later, detach the listener (in onDestroy, etc)
userRef
  .child(uid)
  .child("rapports")
  .removeEventListener(rapportListener)
```

Comment: i tried ur code but it's the same infinite loop

Comment: @MouadhLaabidi That's exactly what I said on the first line. You'll need to provide the rest of your code to find out where it is.

Comment: ahh i got it know .. and thank you i figured out the problem it wasn't there but like you said